# Graminae pollen in Thailand

Tags: health, thailand

I'll go in Thailand in the first 2 weeks of October and I have a mild allergy to **pollen** of graminae (weed, rice, corn, mais, wheat and so on).

We are going to Bangkok and to the northern part of the country, such as Chang Mai, Chang Rai and the surroundings.

Do you know if in that season I will encounter graminae pollen there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spent the first 2 weeks of October in Bangkok, Chang Mai and the Golden triangle, I never had problems with pollens despite my mild allergy.